# How to create a new array from the individual variables in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I've following variables' code which are to be inserted into an array. That is the new array should contain all these variables as its elements. How could I achieve this? My code for variables is as follows:

```
  $question_id        = $request['question_id'];
  $reported_site_id   = SITE_ID;
  $reported_user_type = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_TYPE];
  $reported_user_id   = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_ID];
  $que_issue          = implode(",", $request['que_issue']);
  $que_issue_comment  = $request['que_issue_comment']; 
  $que_issue_date     = time();
```

The new array should be called `$form_data`. Also pleas elet me know how to access the array elements the simplest and efficient way.

Comment: $array = new array($value1, $value2);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way

```
$form_data = array(
  'question_id'        => $request['question_id'],
  'reported_site_id'   => SITE_ID,
  'reported_user_type' => $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_TYPE],
  'reported_user_id'   => $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_ID],
  'que_issue'          => implode(",", $request['que_issue']),
  'que_issue_comment'  => $request['que_issue_comment'],
  'que_issue_date'     => time()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$question_id        = $request['question_id'];
$reported_site_id   = SITE_ID;
$reported_user_type = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_TYPE];
$reported_user_id   = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_ID];
$que_issue          = implode(",", $request['que_issue']);
$que_issue_comment  = $request['que_issue_comment']; 
$que_issue_date     = time();

$form_data = array();

$form_data['question_id'] = $question_id;
$form_data['reported_site_id'] = $reported_site_id;
$form_data['reported_user_type'] = $reported_user_type;
$form_data['reported_user_id'] = $reported_user_id;
$form_data['que_issue'] = $que_issue;
$form_data['que_issue_comment'] = $que_issue_comment;
$form_data['que_issue_date'] = $que_issue_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$form_data = array();
$form_data['question_id'] = $question_id    = $request['question_id'];
$form_data['reported_site_id'] =   $reported_site_id   = SITE_ID;
$form_data['reported_user_type'] =  $reported_user_type = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_TYPE];
$form_data['reported_user_id'] =   $reported_user_id   = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_ID];
$form_data['que_issue'] =   $que_issue    = implode(",", $request['que_issue']);
$form_data['que_issue_comment'] =   $que_issue_comment  = $request['que_issue_comment']; 
$form_data['que_issue_date'] =   $que_issue_date     = time();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compact` function

https://www.php.net/compact

```
  $question_id        = $request['question_id'];
  $reported_site_id   = SITE_ID;
  $reported_user_type = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_TYPE];
  $reported_user_id   = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_ID];
  $que_issue          = implode(",", $request['que_issue']);
  $que_issue_comment  = $request['que_issue_comment']; 
  $que_issue_date     = time();

  $new_array = compact('question_id', 'reported_site_id', '..');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [compact](http://www.php.net/compact)

```
$form_date = compact('question_id', 'reported_site_id', 'reported_user_type', 'reported_user_id', 'que_issue', 'que_issue_comment', 'que_issue_date');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $form_data = array();
    $form_data[] = ('question_id'=>$request['question_id']);
    $form_data[] = ('reported_site_id'=>SITE_ID);
    $form_data[] = ('reported_user_type'=>$_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_TYPE]);
    $form_data[] = ('reported_user_id'=>$_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_ID]);
    $form_data[] = ('que_issue'==>implode(",", $request['que_issue']));
    $form_data[] = ('que_issue_comment'=>$request['que_issue_comment']); 
    $form_data[] = ('que_issue_date'=>time());
```